# c++: code works on local file but needs to be changed to fetch and read from http server

Tags: c++

I need to change the following piece of code, and instead of reading from local file it needs to read from file on http server.
Any ideas on how i could achieve this by changing this code.

fahd

Open the file in binary mode and seek to the end to determine file size

Comment: am sure someone will suggest libCURL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading a file on an http server you need to make an http request to the server. You may use a library like libcurl to achieve this.

Avoid using C-casts.